# how to use multiple broker? (Stomp, ActiveMQ and activemessaging)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemq-classic, stomp, activemessaging

I am using ActiveMQ with stomp and activemessaging. 
I tried to follow the configuration steps in 
http://code.google.com/p/activemessaging/wiki/Configuration

In my broker.yml, I have the following config

```
development:
    adapter: stomp
    login: ""
    passcode: ""
    host: localhost
    port: 61613
    reliable: true
    reconnectDelay: 5

foo:
adapter: stomp
login: ""
passcode: ""
host: xx.xx.xx.xx
port: 61614
reliable: true
reconnectDelay: 5

test: .....
production: ......
```

In my messaging.rb, I have...

```
ActiveMessaging::Gateway.define do |s|
  s.queue :hi_world, '/queue/HiWorld', {}, 'foo'
end
```

But this doesn't seem to work, the messages are not queued in HiWorld queue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Matet

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to help, but the question is poorly formatted - I can't tell what the broker.yml file looks like.  It looks like the indentation level is wrong on the foo: definition; it needs to be under the level of the environment (development:), and it looks to be at the same level, and so will not be used by the broker config.